# Redis local or hosted when developing node/express app?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

If you were using connect-redis as your client for session management, would you run redis locally or connect to a remote 3rd party service like RedisToGo? Would it matter? Would you care?

I'm trying to get my local development environment right and never used Redis before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

local. Much faster. Does not require working Internet connection. Redis is open source, freely available, easy to install, and easy to operate. Just go for it.